# В постраничной навигации не сохраняются параметры, переданные чекбоксами

Tags: php, постраничный-вывод

При поиске формируется вот такая ссылка:

```
?view=search&searchname=&genre=1&start-film=1987&end-film=2015&start-price-film=150&end-price-film=900&x=0&y=0
```

Если не выбирать чекбоксы, а использовать только имя, то все работает нормально, но если же, наоборот, выбирать через чекбоксы, а имя не использовать, то при переходе на последующую страницу происходит "выкидывание" из поиска с ошибкой (что не выбран ни один чекбокс) и в ссылке значение `genre[]`, в которую переходят айдишники чекбоксов, меняет значение... Вот такая ссылка получается:

```
?view=search&searchname=&genre=Array&start-film=1987&end-film=2015&start-price-film=150&end-price-film=900&x=0&y=0&str=2
```

И всплывает варнинг:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
> foreach() in
> S:\home\doplom\www\controller\control.php
> on line 41

Если самостоятельно изменить `genre=Array` на `genre=1`, то все работает, из чего следует вывод, что теряется параметр (`genre` - выбранные чекбоксы).
Чтобы не смущала ошибка про foreach, покажу, как я параметр обрабатываю:

```
$genre = array();
    if($_GET['genre']){
        foreach($_GET['genre'] as $genid){
            $genid = (int)$genid;
            $genre[$genid] = $genid;
        }
        print_arr($_GET);
        print_arr($genre);
    }
    if($genre){
        $cat = implode(',',$genre);
    }
```

Почему он теряется, не могу понять, чтобы выбранный параметр оставался в параметрах чекбокса прописано:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="<?=$item['kategory_id']?>" id="<?=$item['kategory_id']?>" <?php if($item['kategory_id'] == $genre[$item['kategory_id']]) echo "checked" ?>/>
```

В функции навигации тоже запоминание ссылки прописано:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){
        foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
            if($key!='str') $url .= "{$key}={$value}&";
        }
    }
```

Ребят, выручайте, уже всю голову сломал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема как раз в этой функции навигации для ключа `$_GET['genre'] $value` является массивом, и поскольку вы `$value` напрямую в строку пишите, в итоге у вас получается неправильный url с `genre=Array`.